# In a text file i have fifth column with some value.How can i change the values of fifth column by awk command

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

In a text file i have fifth column with some value.
1   44540   23.25   82.25   0.25    0.0315  0.006
like that i have 50 rows.

How can i change the values of fifth column by awk command.

Comment: Why don't you walk around StackOverflow answers some minutes? There may be thousand of them that solve your question.

Comment: hey hey guys, that link is for shortening i.e. rounding column, what if lady have 50 new values to change

Comment: @fedorqui How come i don't get credited as marking as duplicate ? Not really bothered, just wondering ?

Comment: @josifoski what if lady is on a spaceship, it's irrelevant as the question doesn't have enough information to make more than an educated guess at what they want.

Comment: @User112638726 to my understanding, the closing mechanism removes the "possible duplicate" comments when the question is closed.

Comment: @fedorqui so me flagging it just adds a comment instead of actually flagging it ?

Comment: @User112638726 what was your exact action? Did you click "Close" and then selected "possible duplicate"?

Comment: @fedorqui Yeah, is that different from just selecting duplicate ?

Comment: @User112638726 no, no, just wondering if you already had access to this privilege. So yes, when you click "possible duplicate" you are voting to close. Funny thing is that when you do it, `close` appears as `close (1)` (if there is one vote to close, etc), whereas in this case it did not have anything there. But when I clicked in "close" I could select the link you provided as possible duplicate. And since I have a gold badge in [awk], it got closed automatically with the "duplicate hammer" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). But yes, if you did vote to close, you should be credited.

Comment: @User112638726 wait, you have ~500 rep and voting to close starts at 3000 (http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). So you did flag the question, not voted to close. It is different.

Comment: @fedorqui ahh right, thanks for the links. Guess theres no point in me flagging anything then :)

Comment: @User112638726 no, it is perfectly fine to do so and very useful for the site's health. What I did not remember is that flagging was creating this comment automatically.

Comment: @User112638726 look, this is what I meant with `close (4)`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qHuVn.png Just seen in http://stackoverflow.com/q/30771304/1983854

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{$5=$5+1;print}'
```

Assigning to $5 automatically recalculates $0.  "print" prints the new $0.

Comment: if i want to change the value of  5,6,and 7th column simultaneously what I should do